# Integrating IMA iOS SDK

Tags: ios

I have integrated google SDK manually without cocoapods because I'm using it inside a static library. And I have added all the frameworks (AVFoundation,..Etc) needed for IMA SDK.

My app getting crashed whenever I am trying to set IMASettings with the language.

Here is the error:

> +[NSDictionary gtm_dictionaryWithHttpArgumentsString:]: 
>       "unrecognized selector sent to"

This is my code :

```
- (IMASettings *)createIMASettings {
    IMASettings *settings = [[IMASettings alloc] init];
    settings.language = @"en";
    return settings;
}
```

I have initialized the ads loader here :

```
self.adsLoader = [[IMAAdsLoader alloc] initWithSettings:[self createIMASettings]];
```

Comment: Hi, I have that in this way and works:  self.adsLoader = [[IMAAdsLoader alloc] initWithSettings:nil];
self.adsLoader.delegate = self;

Answer (score 1):

You miss a category with the method `gtm_dictionaryWithHttpArgumentsString`
now most likely, this IS part of the SDK but haven't setup the linker right

add `-ObjC` to your app's linker flags

[image]

---

if that isn't it, you're missing another framework from google - the google toolbox for mac